# Recursive Async HttpWebRequests

Tags: c#, silverlight-4.0, asynchronous, recursion, httpwebrequest

Suppose I have the following class:

```
Public class FooBar
{

   List<Items> _items = new List<Items>();

   public List<Items> FetchItems(int parentItemId)
   {

     FetchSingleItem(int itemId);

     return _items
   }

   private void FetchSingleItem(int itemId)
   {

   Uri url = new Uri(String.Format("http://SomeURL/{0}.xml", itemId);
   HttpWebRequest webRequest = (HttpWebRequest)HttpWebRequest.Create(url);

   webRequest.BeginGetResponse(ReceiveResponseCallback, webRequest);

   }

   void ReceiveResponseCallback(IAsyncResult result)
   {

     // End the call and extract the XML from the response and add item to list

     _items.Add(itemFromXMLResponse);

     // If this item is linked to another item then fetch that item 


     if (anotherItemIdExists == true)
     {
        FetchSingleItem(anotherItemId);
     }


   }

}
```

There could be any number of linked items that I will only know about at runtime.

What I want to do is make the initial call to `FetchSingleItem` and then wait until all calls have completed then return `List<Items>` to the calling code.

Could someone point me in the right direction? I more than happy to refactor the whole thing if need be (which I suspect will be the case!)

Comment: Why are you not using WebClient.DownloadStringAsync?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Getting the hang of asynchronous coding is not easy especially when there is some sequential dependency between one operation and the next.  This is the exact sort of problem that I wrote the `AsyncOperationService` to handle, its a cunningly short bit of code.

First a little light reading for you:  [Simple Asynchronous Operation Runner – Part 2](http://geekswithblogs.net/codingbloke/archive/2010/10/15/simple-asynchronous-operation-runner-ndash-part-2.aspx).  By all means read part 1 but its a bit heavier than I had intended.  All you really need is the `AsyncOperationService` code from it.

Now in your case you would convert your fetch code to something like the following.

```
 private IEnumerable<AsyncOperation> FetchItems(int startId)
 {
     XDocument itemDoc = null;
     int currentId = startId;

     while (currentID != 0)
     {
        yield return DownloadString(new Uri(String.Format("http://SomeURL/{0}.xml", currentId), UriKind.Absolute),
             itemXml => itemDoc = XDocument.Parse(itemXml) );

        // Do stuff with itemDoc like creating your item and placing it in the list.

        // Assign the next linked ID to currentId or if no other items assign 0

     }
 }
```

Note the blog also has an implementation of `DownloadString` which in turn uses WebClient which simplifies things. However the principles still apply if for some reason you must stick with HttpWebRequest.  (Let me know if you are having trouble creating an `AsyncOperation` for this)

You would then use this code like this:-

```
int startId = GetSomeIDToStartWith();
Foo myFoo = new Foo();

myFoo.FetchItems(startId).Run((err) =>
{
    // Clear IsBusy
    if (err == null)
    {
        // All items are now fetched continue doing stuff here.

    }
    else
    {
        // "Oops something bad happened" code here
    }
}
// Set IsBusy
```

Note that the call to `Run` is asynchronous, code execution will appear to jump past it before all the items are fetched.  If the UI is useless to the user or even dangerous then you need to block it in a friendly way.  The best way (IMO) to do this is with the `BusyIndicator` control from the toolkit, setting its `IsBusy` property after the call to `Run` and clearing it in the `Run` callback.

Answer (score 1):

All you need is a thread sync thingy. I chose `ManualResetEvent`.

However, I don't see the point of using asynchronous IO since you always wait for the request to finish before starting a new one. But the example might not show the whole story?

```
Public class FooBar
{
   private ManualResetEvent _completedEvent = new ManualResetEvent(false);
   List<Items> _items = new List<Items>();

   public List<Items> FetchItems(int parentItemId)
   {
      FetchSingleItem(itemId);
      _completedEvent.WaitOne();
      return _items
   }

   private void FetchSingleItem(int itemId)
   {
       Uri url = new Uri(String.Format("http://SomeURL/{0}.xml", itemId);
       HttpWebRequest webRequest = (HttpWebRequest)HttpWebRequest.Create(url);

       webRequest.BeginGetResponse(ReceiveResponseCallback, webRequest);
   }

   void ReceiveResponseCallback(IAsyncResult result)
   {
        // End the call and extract the XML from the response and add item to list

        _items.Add(itemFromXMLResponse);

        // If this item is linked to another item then fetch that item 


        if (anotherItemIdExists == true)
        {
            FetchSingleItem(anotherItemId);
        }
        else
            _completedEvent.Set();
   }
}
```

Comment: I presume you mean `_completedEvent.WaitOne()` as `Wait()` doesn't exist?  I have tried this already and it just waits forever. Stepping through the code it hits the `WaitOne()` then never reaches the `ReceiveResponseCallBack` method.

Comment: Yes. I meant `WaitOne()`. What you say is impossible if the web server exists and are responding. The `BeginGetResponse` is invoked before the event starts to wait. The action IO is being made in a thread pool thread and should not be affected of the waiting thread. Something else in your code must be wrong.

Comment: If I remove the `WaitOne()` it immediately returns the `_items` to the calling code (the code that called `FetchItems` but continues to run in the background (stepping through the callback method).  If the `WaitOne` is there it simply stops all processing and hangs.

Comment: Set a break point in the top of the callback. Then step through the code to make sure that the Begin method is being called with proper info. I use the async methods all the time and I've never had the problems you describe. Also make sure that nothing throws exceptions that could prevent you from reporting completed.

Comment: @Barry: I would not recommend that you using a blocking approach like this.  If you really feel you must then move it off the main UI thread using a Background worker before you block with a `WaitOne`.  You will also need a mechanism to handle error conditions so that FetchItems does not block indefinitely and does not appear to completed properly when it hasn't.